# Python matplotlib: Rotate x-axis labels of a Bar-Chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, pareto-chart

Just started with coding and I have not yet fully understood the plotting. 
I am creating a Pareto-Chart and my Bar-Labels are quiet long. I copied from another thread the plotcode. How can I rotate the labeling (45 or 90 degrees)

The code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(counts_clean_cutoff['error'], counts_clean_cutoff["counts"], color="C0")
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(counts_clean_cutoff['error'], counts_clean_cutoff["cumpercentage"], color="C1", marker="D", ms=7)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())

ax.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C0")
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C1")
plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: plt.xticks(rotation=45)

Comment: Hey, I have seen that in another question, but it did not work. Finally it worked with: ax.set_xticklabels(counts_clean_cutoff['error'], rotation=45 )